# How to generate this expression in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am using [lobos](http://github.com/budu/lobos) to create a set of tables:

```
(create
  (table :users
    (integer :id 20)
    (varchar :name 100)))
```

The schema of a table is kept in a seq:

```
([:integer :id 20] [:varchar :name 100])
```

How can I generate that expression with the seq? I find *clojure.contrib/apply-macro* may be used, but are there other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following macro:

```
(defmacro table-create [name coll]
  `(~'create
    (~'table ~name ~@(map (fn [r]
                            (let [[type c v] r]
                              (list (symbol (subs (str type) 1)) c v)))
                          coll))))
```

Here is a sample run:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(table-create :users ([:integer :id 20] [:varchar :name 100])))
;=>     (create
         (table :users
                (integer :id 20)
                (varchar :name 100)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why *macroexpand-1* just outputs *(create ([:integer :id 20] [:varchar :name 100]))* with lein?

Comment: @DanielWu The macro needs to be renamed to table-create, I have updated the answer.